# dshow command is listing device name different from actual device name

Tags: ffmpeg

I have used the command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_devices true -i dummy
```

to list the devices, but if device name is in language other than English then
device name shown by FFmpeg and actual differ. How can I solve this mismatch
problem? This image shows the device name in Spanish:

[image: in Spanish]

This image shows the device name as read by FFmpeg:

[image: as read by FFmpeg]

Comment: Try to change the code page to UTF-8 as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500

Comment: that looks the same to me [?] or are you referring to the international characters being mangled [which I might be able to fix up]

Comment: Yes the special character ó present in mic name is changed to two special charaters.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for me:

`chcp 65001 & ffmpeg -hide_banner -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

I get back than:

[dshow @ 0000000000406b40]  "Kopfhörermikrofon"